# Div mask Textarea contents when it drag down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a Textarea box inside of div. however when I drag the textarea and push it down. Div start to mask all the contents. Is any way to expand div's heigh when user try to drag textarea down. Can I do it in css or do I need javascript or jquery?

```
<div style="height:400px; width:200px; background:yellow; overflow:hidden"> 
    <textarea style="widht:150; height:200px;"></textarea>       
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y9hy9/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y9hy9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/DEgEw/1/

```
<div style="min-height:400px; min-width:200px; background:yellow; width: auto; display: inline-block; overflow:hidden"> 
    <textarea style="widht:150; height:200px;"></textarea>       
</div>
```

I would suggest using min-height and min-width instead of fixed height and width. Also display: inline-block will adjust width to fit the textarea and you can always add a br tag to prevent other divs to go beside your wrapper div